# How to transform rgb (three bytes) to one byte for bitmap format?

Tags: c++, graphics, bitmap

I have data for every pixel red one byte, green one byte, blue one byte. I need to pack this to 8 bits bitmap, so I have only one byte for pixel. How to transform rgb (three bytes) to one byte for bitmap format ?
( I am using C++ and cannot use any external libraries)

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood how to form a bitmap structure. You do not need to pack (somehow) 3 bytes into one. That is not possible after all, unless you throw away information (like using [special image formats GL_R3_G3_B2](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Format#Special_color_formats)).

The [BMP file format wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) shows detailed BMP format : it is a header, followed by data. Now depending on what you set in your header, it is possible to form a BMP image containing RBG data component, where each component is one byte.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to decide how many bits you want to allocate for each color.

1. 3bit per color will overflow a byte (9bits)
2. 2bits per color will underflow;

In three byte RGB bitmap you have one byte to represent each color's intensity. Where 0 is minimum and 255 is max intensity. When you convert it to 1 byte bitmap (assuming you will choose 2bits per color ) transform should be:

```
1-byte red color/64
```

i.e you will get only 4 shades out of a spectrum of 265 shades per color.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to [produce 256 colors palette that best fits your source image.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_quantization#Algorithms)

Then you need to [dither the image using the palette you've generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dithering#Digital_photography_and_image_processing).

Both problems have many well-known solutions. However, it's impossible to produce high-quality result completely automatic: for different source images, different approaches work best. For example, here's the Photoshop UI that tunes the parameters of the process:

[image]